# How to find if a public website page is using POST method?

Tags: c#, java, javascript

How to find if a public website page is using POST method? If it is using, how to find out the parameters it uses in that method without looking at the source code, of course looking at the source code of html?

Comment: have you tried fiddler?

Comment: What do you mean, "using POST method"?  Using it how?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You cannot magically see what parameters it takes without looking at what parameters it takes.

Comment: ok.. let me explain.. I want to collect data of trains for the given 'source and destination' pairs from an public website. Of course i dont want to do this manually. But want to do this automatically. I know now it uses POST method. But how do i send my input to the page? i dont know post parameters it uses! Is it possible anyway how to find this.. solutions are much appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that just by looking at html source code. but you can follow below steps to find out what APIs the website backend is using and whether it's GET or POST.

> Open the website in chrome -> Open developer console(Ctrl + Shift + I)
>   -> Go to Network Tab -> Apply XHR filter. -> Reload the page .

Now you'll be able to see all the network request details made by page.

Answer (score 1):

1. Look at the HTML code and search for `<form>` tags,
2. Look at the JavaScript on the page and look for Ajax requests
3. Use Firebug or similar tools (press F12) to debug the web page and/or monitor the requests
4. Use a network monitoring tool like Wireshark

Option 3 is possibly the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to be able to get stuff from a POST method from a website you did not develop yourself. That is why people use the POST method.
More about Post and Get: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp